# CSS universal selector for numbers?

Tags: css, selector

I am trying to target an element that has a dynamic number associated with it. For example, one time it may be

`#widget-5_yikes_mc_widget-__i__ > div.widget-top > div.widget-title > h4:before`

and another instance of it may be

`#widget-8_yikes_mc_widget-__i__ > div.widget-top > div.widget-title > h4:before`

Is there a way I can target those elements regardless of the number associate to it? Maybe using a universal selector of some sorts? I've never used them so I'm having a little difficulty getting it set up.

The css I was trying was :

`#widget-^_yikes_mc_widget-__i__ > div.widget-top > div.widget-title > h4:before`

I'm not even sure this is possible with CSS

Comment: It sounds like you want to use attribute selectors. As long as you're requirement doesn't include IE6, you should be good to go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
*[id^="widget-"] > div.widget-top > div.widget-title > h4:before
```

This uses the [attribute prefix selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) from CSS3.

If it also must end with `_yikes_mc_widget-__i__` then:

```css
*[id^="widget-"][id$="_yikes_mc_widget-__i__"] > div.widget-top > div.widget-title > h4:before
```

Or, if you can get away with just selecting something that has `yikes_mc_widget` in the middle:

```css
*[id*="_yikes_mc_widget"] > div.widget-top > div.widget-title > h4:before
```

Comment: See also the MDN article on attribute selectors for browser compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Your second response there seems to be doing just what I need. Let me play with it, test it out and mark it as correct if all is good. Thanks Phrogz!

Comment: You're welcome; see my last edit for a substring match that is simpler and perhaps gives you what you need.

Comment: I deleted my answer because if your second example works it should be the correct answer.

Comment: I have another one that I need to target, which appends a number to the end: example: `#widget-21_yikes_mc_widget-2 > div.widget-top > div.widget-title > h4:before` . Going off the working example, would it be something like: `[id^="widget-"][id$="_yikes_mc_widget-"] > div.widget-top > div.widget-title > h4:before`

Comment: and `*[id*="_yikes_mc_widget"] > div.widget-top > div.widget-title > h4:before` did just what I needed it to. It targets all widgets with _yikes_mc_widget in the ID. Thats amazing. Thanks so much Phrogz!

Comment: FYI, you can also declare attribute selectors without the quotes, like so: `*[id*=_yikes_mc_widget]`. Not an impact in selector performance whatsoever, but anything that helps DRY is always welcome. Read more here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs

Answer (score 1):

I'm slow but [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/willthemoor/Mp6ua/) as an example. There's no number selector but as noted, you can use other bits of the ID to target those elements.

```
div {
    background-color: grey;
}
div[id^=widget] {
    background-color: green;
}
div[id^=widget][id$=__i__] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Reference:
http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors